# What value can be got by GetActualTorque() function on Elmo API?

Tags: elmo

We are trying to control more than 20 motors daisy chained together.
We are using an Elmo controller (Platinum Maestro) as controller, communicating via EtherCAT.
The PC environment is Ubuntu 20.04, and the control is attempted using "Maestro Administrative and Motion API" provided by Elmo.

The values obtained by EASII, a Windows application of Elmo, and the API's GetActualPosition() function match.
Since the unit of the torque value in EASII is electric current, I assume that it is the current value that is acquired by the GetActualTorque() function.
However, the value that can be acquired by the GetActualTorque() function and the value displayed on the external power supply are different, and the function value is larger.
Are the units obtained by the API different? Is there some influence of daisy-chain connection? We would like to know if anyone knows what the cause is.